# Is there any API available to perform publisher operations on WSO2 Governance Registry?

Tags: registry, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I have read through the documents and I saw that there is a governance and a web service API available, but I do not understand the execution part. I would like to understand how to execute below operations through an API.

1) how can I publish service (SOAP or REST) using the API ?

2) how can I configure values to different items in publisher portal using API ?

Overview Categorization Contacts Interface Security Doc links Tags Taxonomy

3) how can I upload the artifacts WSDL, schema, policy etc ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Governance Registry supports [Registry REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Registry+REST+API) and [Governance REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Governance+REST+API). You can use these APIs to do all the above operations and also these documentations contain sample curl requests which you can get an idea of executing.

For the resources specific operations, refer to documentation [1] & [2]

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Resources+with+REST+API

[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Governance+REST+API#GovernanceRESTAPI-Assets

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 ways to add resources remotely to G-Reg

**i. Using registry [REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Resources+with+REST+API#ResourceswithRESTAPI-Addaresource)**

[Add a Resource using registry REST API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Resources+with+REST+API#ResourceswithRESTAPI-Addaresource)

[Retrieving Associations Using WSO2 G-Reg Registry API Explained](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/08/retrieving-associations-using-registry.html)

**ii. Using [publisher API](https://denuwanthi.wordpress.com/2016/04/06/wso2-governance-registryusing-publisher-rest-api-to-upload-wsdlswagger/) (G-Reg 5.0.0 or above)**

Create Schema:(Upload file)

Request

```
URL:https://<host>:<port>/publisher/assets/schema/apis/schemas?type=schema

Method: POST
Header:Cookie: JSESSIONID=<SESSION-ID>

Payload:(form data)
schema : schema
schema_file : <schema file name>.xsd
filename : <schema file name>.xsd
schema_file_name : <schema file name>.xsd
file_version : <version>
addNewSchemaFileAssetButton : Create
```

File Upload:

***Upload the schema file. Give the field entry as ‘schema_file’***

Response should be:

```
Status: 200 OK
```

To upload a zip file just change the schema_file,filename and schema_file_name values with zip file name.(I didn't test this but should work according to the source code.)

**iii. Using Governance API - only for hosted content type resources. (G-Reg 5.2.0 or above)**

[image: Content type resource upload - WSDL sample request]

What is the version your using?
Hope these details will help you!

Comment: @thusarak These are really great information. Thanks for your help. I am using version 5.3. 

I have another question off the original topic. I am trying to look for vmware image but I am not able to find that anywhere. I see the available VM image is of version 4.x.x. 

Information are scattered everywhere. Please see if you can provide any info related to acquiring latest VM imagae. I would really appreciate your reply.

Thanks,
Prashant

Comment: you  mean VMware image of ubuntu+G-Reg? but you can create your own VM image within 10mins(9m generate the VM image.) Please clarify why you are doing this? Anyone can have an up and running WSO2 G-Reg within 2mins with samples.

Comment: I have tried to upload wsdl using advanced google rest API. In response I get html content (publisher portal).

Comment: you mean advance rest client? as far as I remember you should get an HTTP 201. Will you share the screenshot of your request and console ?

Comment: I opened another question, it has a screenshot. If you can look at that.

Comment: please provide the link to your question.